# How to mock OkHttpClient request to external URL?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, okhttp

I have this code in my service:

```
public String requestValue() {
  Call call = okHttpClient.newCall(new Request.Builder().url("external-url").build());
  Response response = call.execute();
  return response.body().string();
}
```

How can I mock the result of this call in a Junit test?

```
public void testRequestValue() {
  // TODO mock http response
  String result = myService.requestValue();
  assertEquals("value", result);
}
```

note: naive solution with Mockito does not work. `Mockito.eq` does not trigger on `Request` objects (seems like `Request.equals` provides incorrect result for identical requests).

```
Request request = new Request.Builder().url("external-url").build();
Response response = new Response.Builder()
  .request(request)
  .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_2)
  .code(200)
  .message("")
  .body(ResponseBody.create("value", MediaType.get("application/json")))
  .build();

Call call = Mockito.mock(Call.class);
Mockito.when(call.execute()).thenReturn(response);
Mockito.when(okHttpClientMock.newCall(Mockito.eq(request))).thenReturn(call);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [wiremock](https://wiremock.org) or the MockServer provided by [okhttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver)